# Update SetupProxy target dynamically

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am developing a tenant application with Django backend and React.js as a frontend framework. And using `http-proxy-middleware` to proxy the request to backend server. For different kind of tenants we need to update target value of `createProxyMiddleware` dynamically. Typically we can use

```py
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://t1.demo.local:8000/',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false
    })
  );
};
```

Here i want to update target dynamically for different tenant client. How i can achieve that. Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I have a similar requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try the router. Check out the recipe [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/router.md).